# How can I check if an element with a changeable child contains an array property with a certain value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, properties

Can someone please have a look at my code and let me know how I can write this function. I am creating a sequence quiz where the answers have to be placed in the correct order. When The player is happy with their order there is a check answers function. The questions come from an array where a {"correct_order" :1} property is defined for each answer. I'm wondering how I can now write the code to check if {"correct_order" :1} is contained within the answerOneContainer. Below is the questions array and my attempt to check if the container contains {"correct_order" :1} but I am unsure how to write this piece of code:

```
const myQuestions = [
{
    question: "Starting with the most put these countries in order of total population",
    answers: [
        { "correct_order": 5, "details": "Ireland" },
        { "correct_order": 2, "details": "United States" },
        { "correct_order": 3, "details": "Russia" },
        { "correct_order": 1, "details": "China" },
        { "correct_order": 4, "details": "United Kingdom" }
    ]
},

function checkAnswer() {
let score = 0;
if (answerOneContainer.firstElementChild === myQuestions.answers.correct_order(1)) {
    document.getElementById("container1").classList.add("green-border")
} else {
    document.getElementById("container1").classList.add("red-border")
}
```

Comment: What does the answerOneContainer hold? Is it an array?

Comment: answerOneContainer, answerTwoContainer and  so on all contain another div ans1, ans2 and so on. The answers in the array above are then pushed into these child elements in the order shown with a buildQuiz function. The user is then able to swap the child elements around so that answerOneContain may hold ans5 div eventually.  That's when I then need to check to see is answerOneContainer contains the div with the array property correct_order: 1 and answerTwoContainer contains the div with the array property correct_order: 2 and so on...

Comment: Please, put here your html code and the rest of js

Comment: I just posted my html and entire JS in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="quiz" class="quiz-container d-none">
    <div id="question" class="quiz-question"></div>

    <div id="container1" class="answer-container">
        <div id="ans1" class="answer"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="button-container">
        <button id="switch1" class="btn-style"><i class="fas fa-sync switch-button"></i></button>
    </div>

    <div id="container2" class="answer-container">
        <div id="ans2" class="answer"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="button-container">
        <button id="switch2" class="btn-style"><i class="fas fa-sync switch-button"></i></button>
    </div>

    <div id="container3" class="answer-container">
        <div id="ans3" class="answer"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="button-container">
        <button id="switch3" class="btn-style"><i class="fas fa-sync switch-button"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div id="container4" class="answer-container">
        <div id="ans4" class="answer"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="button-container">
        <button id="switch4" class="btn-style"><i class="fas fa-sync switch-button"></i></button>
    </div>

    <div id="container5" class="answer-container">
        <div id="ans5" class="answer"></div>
    </div>

    <button id="quizSubmit" class="quiz-submit btn btn-primary btn-lg">Check Answer</button>
    <button id="nextQuestion" class="quiz-submit btn btn-primary btn-lg d-none">Next Question</button>
</div>


// VARIABLES
const quizQuestion = document.getElementById('question');
const answerOne = document.getElementById('ans1');
const answerTwo = document.getElementById('ans2');
const answerThree = document.getElementById('ans3');
const answerFour = document.getElementById('ans4');
const answerFive = document.getElementById('ans5');
const answerOneContainer = document.getElementById('container1');
const answerTwoContainer = document.getElementById('container2');
const answerThreeContainer = document.getElementById('container3');
const answerFourContainer = document.getElementById('container4');
const answerFiveContainer = document.getElementById('container5');

// QUIZ QUESTIONS ARRAY

const myQuestions = [
{
    question: "Starting with the most put these countries in order of total population",
    answers: [
        { "correct_order": 5, "details": "Ireland" },
        { "correct_order": 2, "details": "United States" },
        { "correct_order": 3, "details": "Russia" },
        { "correct_order": 1, "details": "China" },
        { "correct_order": 4, "details": "United Kingdom" }
    ]
},
{
    question: "Starting with the most put these countries in order of size",
    answers: [
        { "correct_order": 2, "details": "Canada" },
        { "correct_order": 5, "details": "Ireland" },
        { "correct_order": 3, "details": "Australia" },
        { "correct_order": 4, "details": "Mexico" },
        { "correct_order": 1, "details": "Russia" }
    ]
},
{
    question: "Starting with the most put these languages in order of most spoken",
    answers: [
        { "correct_order": 2, "details": "English" },
        { "correct_order": 5, "details": "Arabic" },
        { "correct_order": 3, "details": "Hindustani" },
        { "correct_order": 4, "details": "Spanish" },
        { "correct_order": 1, "details": "Mandarin Chinese" }
    ]
}
]

// BUILD QUIZ FUNCTION

document.getElementById("start-quiz").onclick = function () { buildQuiz() };

let counter = 0;

function buildQuiz() {
document.getElementById("callout").classList.add("d-none");
document.getElementById("quiz").classList.remove("d-none");
quizQuestion.innerHTML = myQuestions[counter].question;
answerOne.innerHTML = myQuestions[counter].answers[0].details;
answerTwo.innerHTML = myQuestions[counter].answers[1].details;
answerThree.innerHTML = myQuestions[counter].answers[2].details;
answerFour.innerHTML = myQuestions[counter].answers[3].details;
answerFive.innerHTML = myQuestions[counter].answers[4].details;    
};

// SWAP ANSWERS FUNCTION

let answerContainers = {
"container1": answerOneContainer,
"container2": answerTwoContainer,
"container3": answerThreeContainer,
"container4": answerFourContainer,
"container5": answerFiveContainer,
}

function swapAnswersContainer(switchButton, container1, container2) {
document.getElementById(switchButton).addEventListener('click', () => {
$("#" + container1).children(":first").slideToggle('fast');
$("#" + container2).children(":first").slideToggle('fast', function () {



answerContainers[container2].appendChild(answerContainers[container1].firstElementChild);
    answerContainers[container1].appendChild(answerContainers[container2].firstElementChild);
});
$("#" + container1).children(":first").slideToggle('fast');
$("#" + container2).children(":first").slideToggle('fast');
});
}

swapAnswersContainer("switch1", "container1", "container2");
swapAnswersContainer("switch2", "container2", "container3");
swapAnswersContainer("switch3", "container3", "container4");
swapAnswersContainer("switch4", "container4", "container5");

// CHECK ANSWER FUNCTION

document.getElementById("quizSubmit").onclick = function () { checkAnswer() };

function checkAnswer() {
document.getElementById("quizSubmit").classList.add("d-none");
document.getElementById("nextQuestion").classList.remove("d-none");

let score = 0;
if (answerOneContainer.firstElementChild === "correct_order": "1") {
    document.getElementById("container1").classList.add("green-border")
} else {
    document.getElementById("container1").classList.add("red-border")
}
};

// NEXT QUESTION FUNCTION

document.getElementById("nextQuestion").onclick = function () { nextButton() };

function nextButton() {
if (counter >= myQuestions.length) {
    counter = 0;
    return;
}
counter++;
buildQuiz();
document.getElementById("nextQuestion").classList.add("d-none");
document.getElementById("quizSubmit").classList.remove("d-none");
};
```